# Python - Display Entered Information and Average

Tags: python, google-app-engine, average

I know the title isn't much help but I really don't know what to write for it. What my code is supposed to do is display a page with inputs to enter names and scores and then it goes through some functions in the library.py page to make it list them from highest to lowest like a high score board. And then at the bottom there needs to be an average score. But I am having a really hard time with this. First of all when I enter information it doesn't even register it. I used a GET method on the form tag but the information isn't going anywhere. It's supposed to go into the url bar at least. But it's not. And I don't even know what to do with the library page. It's just one big mess. If you can help me, thanks.

**main.py**

```
import webapp2

#from library import GameInfo
from page import FormsPage, ResultsPage

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        f = FormsPage()
        r = ResultsPage()

        if self.request.GET:
            user = self.request.GET['name']
            score = self.request.GET['score']

            self.response.write(r.rbegin + r.rbody)

        else:
            self.response.write(f.fbegin + f.fbody + f.fformbox + f.fforms)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

**library.py**

```
class ScoresList():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ''
        self.__score = 0
        #keeps memory of all the scores intered
    def list_scores(self, s):
        self.__score_array.append(s)

    def make_list(self):
        output = ''
        for score in self.__score_array:
            output += name + score
        return output

class Average():
    pass
```

**page.py**

```
class FormsPage(object):
    fbegin = '''<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Post Your High Scores</title>
        <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>'''
    fbody = '''<body>
    <h1>Submit Your High Scores</h1>'''
    fformbox = '''<div> '''
    fforms = '''<form method="GET">
            <label>Name: </label><input type="text" name"name"/>
            <label>Score: </label><input type="text" name"score"/></br>
            <label>Name: </label><input type="text" name"name"/>
            <label>Score: </label><input type="text" name"score"/></br>
            <label>Name: </label><input type="text" name"name"/>
            <label>Score: </label><input type="text" name"score"/></br>
            <label>Name: </label><input type="text" name"name"/>
            <label>Score: </label><input type="text" name"score"/></br>
            <label>Name: </label><input type="text" name"name"/>
            <label>Score: </label><input type="text" name"score"/></br>
            <input type="submit" value="Enter Scores" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>'''

class ResultsPage(object):
    rbegin = '''<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Here are Your High Scores</title>
            <link css/style.css/>
        </head>'''
    rbody = '''<body>
            <div class="scoreboard">
                <h1>High Scores</h1>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>'''
```

Comment: I would start by adding an `action` to your form tag.  I would also change its method to `POST`, so at least you can test the form in your handler.

Comment: Please don't put HTML code inside Python class objects. Firstly, those classes are pointless, since they store no state; you could just use simple variables. But you shouldn't be putting HTML inside Python files anyway, you should use Jinja templates.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the equals sign for your `name` attributes.  Plus, you will have a conflict giving the same name to multiple inputs.

Try `name="name1"` etc.

Comment: Thanks! That helped the results page show up. And now I've given each name attribute it's own unique name. Now I need to figure out how to make it spit out the list of names and scores from highest to lowest and do the average.

Comment: That's a different question, and not the purpose of SO.  Are we doing your homework for you?  If this answer solved the error in your code, mark it as "accepted".  If you have another question, post it in an appropriate forum.  Hint: you do the calculations in python, and spit them out to the template (HTML page) using jinja.